# How can I get an old air conditioner, partially disassembled, down the stairs?

Tags: air-conditioning

I'm not young enough or strong enough to carry a 50-lb air conditioner down the stairs from the second floor to the first floor to dispose of it. This is an old house with steep stairs with narrow treads.

I googled this question and found no solutions, so I decided to disassemble the AC to make it lighter. I got the casing off and removed a few other parts. A voice in the back of my head told me there was some risk to what I was doing, so I googled "dangers of taking apart an air conditioner" and immediately found a list of ways you can kill yourself doing this, like getting electrocuted by the capacitator and releasing freon.

So now I have a partially disassembled air conditioner at the top of the stairs. What should I do now? I hope I don't have to put it back together. I'm stumped.

**I'm looking for a solution that does not involve other people** due to where I live and the pandemic. The "does not involve other people" part is nonnegotiable. Also, the method should not damage the stairs.

Comment: There are a number of junk/recycler services that will come to your house (typically for a fee) and collect things like that. You can also hire somebody of more able-body to do it too.

Comment: Some of the junk places even say in their ads that they can do it without you there - you tell them what to do, step out of the house, they move the stuff and you go back in. But the thing I'd worry about is refrigerant (freon). A picture would help.

Comment: If the bottom of the case is still on, you could get planks and rope and skid it down the stairs without too much effort.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  large thick cardboard box works wonders up and down stairs. I am assuming in my answer that OP cant move it at all

Comment: Get a large laundry tub it will fit in and some rope. At top put in tub and lid on. The tub will ride on 2 or more steps so will not tip. Tie rope around it. Sit and secure self so you will not fall down. Lower it down stairs using rope

Comment: Chris, your suggestion gave me an idea. I could wrap a 1/4" closed-cell foam camping pad around the air conditioner, and then wrap heavy cardboard or a moving blanket around that. Then lower it down the stairs using a rope, as others have suggested. Thoughts? I don't know of a plastic laundry tub that is rugged enough to take a ride down the stairs.

Comment: Either of those could work. In fact you could just wrap it all up in a quilt, anything really that would protect the stairs from scratches and give package a little slipperiness, so that it can slide down the stairs over step. Basically want to avoid letting it thump on the tread of each step so it does not try and roll. Heavy card box would be great.

Comment: Movers strap.  Basically, you need to take a little bit of weight off of it as it goes down each step, but you don't actually need to pick it up and walk with it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok the capacitor will discharge over time and is not going to electrocute you if the unit has been unplugged for any reasonable amount of time (30+ mins typically, leave it overnight if you're scared)

You have a refrigerant circuit inside of the machine and the best you're going to be able to do is remove the small blower motor and fan from in-between the coils, and some assorted plastic/metal ducting.  You DO NOT want to cut or damage any of the copper lines, it is illegal to intentionally vent the refrigeration gases to atmosphere.

The heavy parts are unfortunately full of refrigerant and cannot be separated without having the system recovered by a HVAC tech (if you even can get someone to work on a window unit).  It is possible to separate the 2 coils and compressor from the rest of the sheet metal but it is not recommended. The fins on the coils are extremely sharp, and the copper lines if bent too much will break.

My best recommendation would unfortunately be to have someone come in and move it for you.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I don't even know what happened there! it looks like something got copy pasted on top of its self on accident (oops!) Should be fixed now

Answer (score 3):

You need to put it back together enough so the covers are on it and the freon system won't be broken open by mishandling.  That's the only goal, you don't need to put the controls or vents back together, just the case.

Freon is serious business. #1 it can freeze your fingers to the point of requiring amputation, and someone handling the unit may think they're only being pinched and keep carrying it until it's too late.  #2 it's damaging the ozone layer, so every nation that doesn't begin with "T" and end with "aliban" has laws requiring NOT releasing freon and old units going to a qualified recoverer.   (who draws the old freon out for either re-refining for reuse, or annihilation.)

Generally, cities are well aware of their citizens having thousands of these things, and their "household hazardous materials" units have made arrangements to take care of them.  For instance they are usually accepted on the typical, biannual "large and weird trash day".

### Moving it downstairs

I spent a lot of time with riggers, who taught me to move large objects using the power of my brain.  This job is trivial using rigger's methods, the key is to assume the unit is 600 pounds instead of 60.

If it were me, I would get a piece of thick 1" plywood about 1 inch wider than the machine, use leverage and blocks to lift one end, then slide the machine onto the plywood. Once centered, I would screw or strap the machine down to the plywood (and maybe "before the cover goes back on" might be a good time to do that).

The plywood is to give it a smooth flat bottom so it will slide without hanging up on bolts or protruding screws or rails.

Then I would firmly screw a couple of cleats to the plywood, to have something to attach block and tackle.  I would then use that to control its descent.

(you don't need to gear the block-and-tackle for 600 pounds lol).

I would use painter's tarps in front of it and below it to help it slide easily down the stairs without scratching.

Make sure you have enough rope, i.e. the number of ropes going up/down the stairway x the length of the stairway.  You can't have knots in it if it needs to roll through a pulley.

Comment: Given the price of plywood these days, as well as the level of effort involved, it may be best to hire a junk removal outfit.

Comment: @George Well, OP really wants to DIY it because COVID. OP isn't wrong; COVID is far worse now than in early 2020 with the lockdowns and hoarding... in fact if you exclude the vaccinated from population count, COVID rates are *cataclysmically* worse.   Anyway, the question boils down to "how do I DIY-move things too big to carry".

Comment: Thanks, Harp for the resp. Yeah, I missed that the OP wanted to do this their selves. But given both limitations (age and not wanting to involve anyone else), limits their options.  But that's why I didn't post this as an answer, just a comment. 

This latest covid variance is a great cause of concern,  my daughter in law (who was vaccinated) caught a "break thru" infection and my youngest brother and his wife also got it. Nasty stuff.   One other option, not knowing more info, is "why not let the AC unit sit there until all this stuff is over?????

Comment: The number of cases may be up, but the death rate (according to [worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/)) is actually down slightly from the last time I looked.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this out of your house now, rent an appliance dolly like this

[image: picture of an appliance dolly]

<sup>Image courtesy of Amazon.com, no endorsement of brand or retailer. Image provided purely for example.</sup>

Any of the nationally known moving truck rental chains will have them available, many of the national big-box DIY stores will rent them to you as well. I'm sure you can find a smaller, local place that will rent it, too.

These are designed *explicitly* for moving large, bulky, heavy items up and down stairs.

- The black strap around the middle is designed to cinch tightly around the item, then the crank handle gets it just that extra bit tighter to ensure it doesn't go anywhere
- The wheels make it easy to roll around on level ground
- The rollers (or "stair climbers") on the back make it easy to roll up or down over the lip of each step.

You gently lower the AC unit one step at a time until you're done. If necessary, you could rig up a rope (similar to Harper's answer) around the top cross-bar of the dolly, giving yourself 6" or so of slack for each step. This would prevent it from running away from you, and take the weight for a minute or two if you need to rest along the way.

It is often safer and easier to have one person holding at the top, and another person supporting at the bottom, but, if you're insistent on doing it all alone, this is 100% the way to go. Actually, I'd highly recommend this even if you had several burly guys over to help out - you're also less likely to damage the stairs and/or walls using this.

---

If this still won't work for you - to be honest, it does take some strength, balance, and coordination to use this, and you don't *have* to have it out of the house *immediately* then just leave it where it is until all the fear and panic is over, then you can see other humans and have them help you remove it or do it for you.